# A Windows software to convert google-drive photos to webp?

Tags: windows, media-converter, google-drive, scripting

So, the software needs to download google drive photos.
Then convert them to .webp, then upload them back to google drive.
Then delete the original (.jpg, .png etc) photos from google drive.

It could also be a windows script.
I am on linux, and I need to help a friend.
I know how to do that on bash script (variables, loops, calling apps to download, convert and upload and delete remote files), but cygwin is not working so I cant send him that script...
I have no idea how to code on windows .bat script.

There is this "extension": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-images-to-webp-conve/alehapkmecbigebjbcicmbmjdaolcjhb/related
It says it would convert on local machine, but apparently it want to upload photos to their website and it has a size limit per photo...
I dont want that limit.
I dont want to spend twice GigaBytes of network quota x4!! (ex.: download from gdrive 10GB, upload to their server +10GB, download from their server +-3GB, upload to gdrive +-3GB, when it could just be 13GB and not 26GB).
I want to use the local machine CPU to convert the photos.

Obs.: videos too to .webm would be a plus btw

PS.: I know I could use some virtual machine to install some linux on his windows, but I prefer a native app or script.